# Oracle Eclipse BPEL Designer

Tags: oracle, soa, bpel

Presently I am working on Oracle BPEL with Jdeveloper.Infact,I would like to work with Oracle Eclipse BPEL designer.So, where can I download Oracle eclipse BPEL designer and how to configure it with oracle SOA suite.
Eclipse BPEL editor is available in www.eclipse.org but I dont know how to configure it with oracle SOA suite.

Comment: try with this https://eclipse.org/bpel/install.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle officially supports only jDeveloper as a main tool for Oracle SOA suite.

Unfortunately, I do not think that you will find Oracle-supported Eclipse plugin for Oracle SOA.